# Read rows of only outer table using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
  <table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Some Content </td>
        <td>Some Content </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Some Content </td>
        <td>Some Content </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Some Content </td>
                    <td>Some Content </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Some Content </td>
                    <td>Some Content </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Some Content </td>
                    <td>Some Content </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
<table>
```

I have some HTML and has table content like above. In side a table there are some more tables.

when I read `tr` using `beautifulsoup` like

```
table_grid_1 = soup.find("table", {"id": "GridView1"})
rows = table_grid_1.find("tbody").find_all("tr")
```

rows of inner table also getting read.

```
i.e `print "length " + str(len(rows))` prints 5. but I want to read tr of only outer table like size should be 3
```

How can I read rows of only outer table?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by using the `recursive=False` [parameter](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-recursive-argument) as follows:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
table_grid_1 = soup.find("table", {"id": "GridView1"})
rows = table_grid_1.find("tbody").find_all("tr",recursive=False)
print len(rows)
```

which returns 3.

Comment: It return 3 because 2 td of outer table and 1 td of inner table which includes all tr data inner table as one.

Comment: OP asked for the following: "str(len(rows))` prints 5. but I want to read tr of only outer table like size should be 3". Which is the case for my code. It returns 3 because there are 3 <tr> elements inside the outer table, each of them is stored as a row and is indexable by row[0] to row[2].

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
[x.string for x in soup.select('table > tbody > tr > td') if x not in soup.select('table > tbody > tr > table > tbody > tr > td')]
```

Result: only outer table td content. Note: it will return empty list if outer and inner td equal.

Comment: This solution is taking quite some overhead, since you perform a set subtraction, which requires you to first fully load the entire set and it's contrary set. While the `recursive=False` parameter will only consider direct children of the table, so there is less of a overhead.